# Why can't I attach a second monitor to my mac mini

Tags: mac-mini

Why is it that whenever I plug in a second monitor to my mac mini, using the HDMI port and a converter to VGA, that my main monitor goes black but when I unplug it, it goes back to normal?

Comment: We need more information. What's the year of the Mac mini and what monitors are you using? Having you tried any troubleshooting yourself yet?

Comment: standard it 2 external monitors. Open System Preferences > Displays arrangement

Comment: Please specify the model of Mac Mini you are concerned about, the version of macOS you are running on this Mac Mini, the brand of HDMI > VGA adaptor you are connecting, the brand and model of both monitors, and lastly, the connection you are using from the Mac Mini to your main monitor.